# How to add a div after every 3 elements in *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I am trying to build an angular project .
In my project I want to show a list of books ,I have a SmallBookView Component for a single book and I want to use ngFor to show many other books./
however after every 3 books I need to add a div to separate this books, 
In the end it should look like so

```
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
```

the div separate each line of books in the ui.
I am trying to use ngFor like so

```
<app-small-book-view *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; let _i = index">
  <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="(_i % 3) == 0"></div>
</app-small-book-view>
```

but this is adding the div only inside the SmallBookView instead of between them, how do I add this div between the components>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ng-container` to group multiple components without the container rendering.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; let _i = index">
  <app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
  <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="(_i % 3) == 0"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This answers the question, but it is worth noting that `*ngIf="(_i % 3) == 0"` will create a div after the first `app-small-book-view` and after every third element afterwards instead of after the third `app-small-book-view` as is what is desired.  This is because the indexing is zero-based and `(0 % 3) == 0`.  You might want `*ngIf="(_i % 3) == 2"` instead to add a div after every third element.

Answer (score 6):

This should not be a task for script but rather for CSS:

```
app-small-book-view:nth-child(3n)::after {
    /*the clearfix thing*/
    content: ""; 
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

So your markup will be just linear sequence of children:

```
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
<app-small-book-view></app-small-book-view>
```

Comment: You could also do this via CSS grid

Comment: Yeah. Anything but not use of script for layout purposes.